# Search Bar showing wrong/mixed cell results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a problem in my iOS project. I'm using a search bar to filter my array in my custom tableview to show the matching keywords of the search.

It shows no code errors but obviously there's a problem.

Normally there's over 20+ items in my tableview but when I search, it only shows the first cell that my tableview normally has without searching, the same image for that cell to be exact, but it is not the same cell because each cell has a button showing specific information through a label in that cell. So when I search and a result comes out, it shows the image that the first cell in the tableview has but with the label or info of the correct cell or that matching cell has.

I don't know what it could be. Maybe it's keeping the image of the first cell because it's a custom tableview cell and for some reason it's not filtering out to the correct image. But the weird part that it's the correct cell that is showing because the specific label that each cell has is showing and not the label that the first cell has with the first cell's picture. I hope I'm making sense.

**Code:**

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
if (isFiltered) {
    return [filteredGamesArray count];
}
return [gamesArray count];
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
Game * gameObject;

if (!isFiltered) {
    gameObject = [gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else {
    gameObject = [filteredGamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
```

**searchBar textDidChange**

```
if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isFiltered = NO;
} else {
    isFiltered = YES;
    filteredGamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Game *game in gamesArray) {

        NSString *str = game.gameName;

        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredGamesArray addObject:game];
        }
    }
}
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Also, I don't keep any images or text in my app. I get all the info that populates the tableview cell from a server using json/php/mysql, with images I use a URL.

I'm missing something here. If you need more details please let me know.

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
// Loading Images
NSURL * imgURL = [[gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"gameURL"];
[cell.myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[cell.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.jpg"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use "predicate" for filtering

Comment: Did you get your result in filteredGamesArray array at a searchBar textDidChange

Comment: yes my results in filteredGamesArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSPredicate for searching best option.

```
searchArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.YOURSEARCHKEY contains[c] %@", YOURTEXTFIELD.text];
NSLog(@"%@",resultPredicate);
searchArray = [ORIGNALARRAY filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
NSLog(@"%@",searchArray);
[self.colorTableview reloadData];
```

// Here check if searching is on or off and just update your array like

```
if searching{
     NSURL * imgURL = [[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"gameURL"];
    [cell.myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [cell.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.jpg"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
}else{
    NSURL * imgURL = [[gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"gameURL"];
    [cell.myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [cell.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.jpg"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
}
```

Comment: Since I'm fairly new, what would I put instead of "YOURTEXTFIELD.text" it's only allowing me to put an array

Comment: Yourtextfield just put your searchfield and YOURSEARCHKEY means put that your key from you that you want to searching .  and ORIGNALARRAY array is your main array that you want to perform searching

Comment: The same thing is happening as with the old code, it's showing the correct cell but with the image of the first cell not the image that goes with the exact cell.

Comment: @BroSimple show me your image array. and in your code where you use it

Comment: I added the image code to cellForRowAtIndexPath, I posted it at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @BroSimple gamesArray is your orignal array and i imagine that in your orignal array 2 value one is for gamename and one is your imageurl right ?

Comment: yes correct plus 3 more values, id and 2 nsstrings (labels)

Comment: @BroSimple then you no need to warry you can perform you task with NSPredicate its working fine.

Comment: But the correct image for the current searched cell is not displaying?

Comment: @BroSimple in your question you can not update your cellForRowAtIndexPath your imageview nit fill up with when you performming filter so update it and check it

Comment: How would I do this? This is the problem I'm having

Comment: @BroSimple i just update my answer check it and implement it your problem solve now . its you done it then approve my answer and give me up vote thank you.