# Search model using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

Below is my model class

```
{"ID":1,"Name":"Area 1","Code":"xyz","StartTime":"09:30","EndTime":"13:40"},
{"ID":2,"Name":"Area 2","Code":"xyz","StartTime":"09:00","EndTime":"13:40"},
{"ID":3,"Name":"Area 3","Code":"xyz","StartTime":"10:30","EndTime":"14:40"},
{"ID":4,"Name":"Area 4","Code":null,"StartTime":"09:30","EndTime":"13:30"}]
```

I have retrieved model class value in NSMutableArray and displayed on TableView, Now I need to search name from model class, Below is my code, however its not been working.

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchString];
    for (NSString *key in _arrAlreaList) {

        NSArray *array = [_arrAlreaList valueForKey:key];
        NSArray *tempArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if (tempArray.count > 0) {
            [filteredArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
            [self.tblArea reloadData];
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF. Name contains [cd] %@", searchString];

Comment: Please t ry thiis ...NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchString];

Comment: I want to search within the model class and this will not work.

Comment: hi you have try my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078904/6656894 refer this answe @Kashif

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['Name'] CONTAINS '%@'",YOURSEARCHTEXT];

Comment: For modal Data Array --> [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF. Name == %@", searchString];  or.  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF. Name like %@", searchString];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

   NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.Name contains [c] %@", searchString];
   NSArray *resultArray = [_arrAlreaList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
   NSLog(@"Result Array %@",resultArray);

}
```

Try This !!